# Checking an array for mount points in ruby

Tags: ruby, linux

Warning: Ruby noob

I'm trying to gather a list of file system mounts and cross check that with what I'd expect to see in the list. So, if sysfs is mounted with the correct options then good, if not then bad.

Current script is ugly but works. Is there a better way to do this? I have a dozen more mount points to check but don't want to have to include 60 lines of code to do that.

What I have so far:

```
mounts = []
File.foreach('/proc/mounts') do |line|
  mounts.push line
end

if mounts.include?("rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0\n")
  puts 'rootfs exists'
else
  puts "rootfs doesn't exist"
end


if mounts.include?("sysfs /sys sysfs rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0\n")
  puts 'sysfs exists'
else
  puts "sysfs doesn't exist"
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this:

```
MOUNT_POINTS = {
  rootfs: "rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0\n",
  sysfs:  "sysfs /sys sysfs rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0\n"
}

mounts = []
File.foreach('/proc/mounts') { |line| mounts << line }

MOUNT_POINTS.each do |k, v|
  puts mounts.include?(v) ? "#{k} exists" : "#{k} doesn't exist"
end
```

Now you only need to add all your *mount points* to the `MOUNT_POINTS` hash and all of them will be iterated giving the desired output.

This line

```
puts mounts.include?(v) ? "#{k} exists" : "#{k} doesn't exist"
```

evaluates `mounts.include?(v)` and `puts` a message concatenating `k` (where `k` is the *key* and `v` is the *value* of the current iteration in `MOUNT_POINTS` hash).

So, for example, in the first iteration (in the current `MOUNT_POINTS` hash) that line will become:

```
puts mounts.include?("rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0\n") ? "rootfs exists" : "rootfs doesn't exist"
```

which uses the *ternary operator*, and its equivalent to

```
if mounts.include?("rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0\n")
 puts "rootfs exists"
else
 puts "rootfs doesn't exist"
end
```

---

As a side note, you may notice that i also changed

```
File.foreach('/proc/mounts') do |line|
  mounts.push line
end
```

to

```
File.foreach('/proc/mounts') { |line| mounts << line }
```

Both do exactly the same, you can use either one of them, its just a matter of style.

---

**UPDATE** (per comments)

To write into a file you could first open the file and then run the `MOUNT_POINTS` iteration, but be aware that using `w` option (as in your comment) will truncate the file every time you open it; if you just want to append more lines to the same file, then use `a` option (you can read about all `open` options [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/IO.html#method-c-new-label-IO+Open+Mode)).

So, you can use the `MOUNT_POINTS` iteration as a block for `File.open`:

```
File.open("failures", 'a') do |file|
  MOUNT_POINTS.each do |k, v|
    mounts.include?(v) ? puts("#{k} exists") : file << "#{k} doesn't exist\n"
  end
end
```

This code will first open the `failures` file, then iterate through `MOUNT_POINTS` and when `mounts.include?(v)` is `true` it will print `"#{k} exists"` on *console*, and if its `false` it will append (notice i used `a` option) `"#{k} doesn't exist\n"` to the file; when the iteration ends, the file will then be closed.

Now, what was wrong with your code?

The line

```
puts mounts.include?(v) ? "#{k} exists" : File.open("failures", 'w') { |file| file.write("#{k} doesn't exist\n") }
```

is the same as

```
if mounts.include?(v)
  puts "#{k} exists"
else
  puts File.open("failures", 'w') { |file| file.write("#{k} doesn't exist\n") }
end
```

which reads as: "*if current mount point exists in `mounts` then print in console* **mount point name exists** *, otherwise open a file, replace all its contents with* **mount point name doesn't exist** *, close the file and print in console whatever that method (i.e. `File.open()`) returns."*

In case you are wondering, "*Whats going on with `puts`?*" Remember that `puts` its just another method, so when using a ternary like

```
puts condition? ? "it is true!" : "it is false.."
```

You are just calling `puts` method and assigning a parameter depending con the evaluation of `condition?`, thus `puts "it is true!"`(or `puts("it is true!")`) is executed when `condition` evaluates to `true`.

Ok, i get it, so *what do `File.open()` **is** returning?* It returns the value of the block, in this case, the length written, hence the `24`.

Now, after all this, you might ask? "*So i could just change `w` to `a` in my code (so every time the file opens it doesn't get wiped out) and it will work?*". And the answer would be **yes**, you could do that and it will work:

```
puts mounts.include?(v) ? "#{k} exists" : File.open("failures", 'a') { |file| file.write("#{k} doesn't exist\n") }
```

So its fair to ask, *why all this trouble if you could get away with a simple tweak?* Well, three reasons come to mind:

1. Its less efficient to open and close your file in each iteration.
2. Printing numbers in console doesn't add any value (and may clutter it).
3. It is harder to read.

At the end choose whatever you (and your team) fill more comfortable with, and stick with it.

Happy coding!

Comment: WOW! Not only did you provide an excellen solution you also helped me out by explaining it. Thanks so much!

Comment: @pullsumo Glad to help. Happy coding!

Comment: One last thing if you could. When I try to write the failure results to a file only the last item in the MOUNT_POINTS array is written to the file and the output is numeric for successes. I have `puts mounts.include?(v) ? "#{k} exists" : File.open("failures", 'w') { |file| file.write("#{k} doesn't exist\n") }` and the output is `rootfs exists
sysfs exists
24
24`

Comment: I bow down before your awesomeness!